# Getting percentage value (with or without space before percentage sign) from string using regex

Tags: regex

I need to get percentage value from string

```
20% some text
20 % some
```

Percentage can be with or without space. At first I need to check if the string contains % sign and then get the value 20.

So far I have this

```
[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(%)?
```

I can only get number value if there is a space before percentage sign.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe with `[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+\s?%` or, to get the number without `%` - ``([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)\s?%`` or `[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?=\s?%)`

Answer (score 2):

```
(\d+)\s?%
```

Should do the job. If you're sure your data would always have 0 or 1 space than would be safer.

See https://regex101.com/r/YVM3v5/2 for pretty explanation, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit late but I think it works for you to find the percentage value
it will handle

1. with space and without space ex: 95%,98 %
2. single and decimal value numbers ex: 2.4 %,12%

   ```
    import re 
    pattern ="\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*%"
    matches = re.findall(pattern, text)
   ```